# Python CURL speficied ip address

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I want to make a GET request to retrieve the contents of a web-page or a web service.
I want to send specific headers for this request AND
I want to set the IP address FROM WHICH this request will be sent.
(The server on which this code is running has multiple IP addresses available).

How can I achieve this with Python and its libraries?

Comment: Are you asking for a specific example of how to use urllib (since you tagged it) or looking for any python library for making http requests?

Comment: "as in, selecting the interface that the machine has {one out of many ip addresses}" - no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: @Joe - Right. Is he talking about the endpoint to which he is making the request, or is he talking about modifying the headers on the originating machine? Confused.

Comment: I want to make a GET request to retrieve the contents of a web-page or a web service. I want to send specific headers for this request and I want to set the IP address FROM WHICH this request will be sent. (The server on which this code is running has multiple IP addresses available).

Comment: @Phil: Please **update** the question to contain all the details.  Don't ask people to read the comments as well as the question.  Make the question complete.  Also.  Please read about `urllib2` and focus your question on the parts of `urllib2` you have **specific** questions about.

Comment: @Phil: you can't generally do this; the decision of what interface a request goes out is determined by the OS and the routing table outside the bounds of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked `urllib2` and it won't set the source address (at least not on Python 2.7). The underlying library is `httplib`, which does have that feature, so you may have some luck using that directly.

From the [httplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html):

> `class httplib.HTTPConnection(host[, port[, strict[, timeout[, source_address]]]])`
>
> The optional `source_address` parameter may be a tuple of a (host, port) to use as the source address the HTTP connection is made from.

You may even be able to convince `urllib2` to use this feature by creating a custom `HTTPHandler` class. You will need to duplicate some code from `urllib2.py`, because `AbstractHTTPHandler` is using a simpler version of this call:

```
class AbstractHTTPHandler(BaseHandler):
    # ...
    def do_open(self, http_class, req):
        # ...
        h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout) # will parse host:port
```

Where `http_class` is `httplib.HTTPConnection` for HTTP connections.

*Probably* this would work instead, if patching `urllib2.py` (or duplicating and renaming it) is an acceptable workaround:

```
        h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, source_address=(req.origin_req_host,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options available to you for making http requests. I don't even think there is really a commonly agreed upon "best". You could use any of these:

1. urllib2: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html
2. requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.4/index.html
3. mechanize: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

This list is not exhaustive. Read the docs and take your pick. Some are lower level and some offer rich browser-like features. All of them let you set headers before making request.

Comment: Thank you. How do I set the IP Address though with ANY of these libraries? Thank you!

Comment: You can only set request headers. I dont think its possible to selct which interface it will go out on.

Comment: Thank you. That's a pity though.